# How to have a list of options when clicking a TButton on Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I know that TButton on firemonkey let me add a TPopUp Menu. But it only works when you right click it.

I need make it open right below the button when you do the normal click.

PopupMenu.PopUp(X, Y) is based on the form I believe. How to translate the X,Y of the button (that is deep inside other layouts) to the same coordinate?

And when clicking and the PopUp is shown some weird behavior happens with the selection bar of the popup menu that disappear. The button keeps pressed, that is good.

[image: Expected Appearance]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here:

http://blogs.embarcadero.com/sarinadupont/2013/10/17/463/

Is an example for mobile, but you use in desktop too.

Comment: You should add the relevant parts of the example from the website into your answer directly.

Comment: @nompa That works for me, please as stated add some of the information to complete the answer and I will accept it!